# EPPLus [Nuget] dependencies

Tags: .net, nuget, nuget-package

I'm working on importing EPPlus into one of my projects. Seeing that I don't have any intention on modifying the encapsulated source I'm thinking the best approach is to import the nuget package.

I'm trying to ascertain dependencies prior to importing (namely if the version is for .net core or .net and if so which versions).

When I view the package information at this website I do not see any way to do so and neither do I see when looking at the options available in the nuget command line.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/cli-ref-list

How can I view the dependencies of this package?

Comment: The dependencies appear in the page you linked, in the `.NET Standard 2.0` section. What do you mean `import the nuget package` anyway? You add a NuGet package to a project and NuGet will install any dependencies if needed

Comment: As for `if the version is for .net core or .net` the `Dependencies` section shows it's a .NET Standard 2.0 package.

Comment: Thank you. I'm seeing it now. It's a bit misleading because under the changelog it states "New features in version 4.5:
* .NET Core support" Does this mean they package both inside the same nuget package?

Comment: The dependencies always appear in the "Dependencies" section. It's the same for all NuGet packages. And no, it doesn't target both, it's a single .NET Standard 2.0 package that can be used by both runtimes. If it had runtime specific dependencies, they would appear under the appropriate section in `Dependencies`

Answer (score 1):

As Panagiotis Kanavos wrote as a comment to the question, you can check the dependencies section of the package details page on nuget.org to see which target framework(s) a package supports. However, it unfortunately only shows the dependencies as defined in the nuspec file, which theoretically might not match the libs in the package, but what's more common is when a package only supports a single framework, or doesn't have any dependencies, that the nuspec doesn't contain a dependencies section and therefore nuget.org doesn't tell us which frameworks the package has libraries for.

What you can do is take the url to a package detail page on nuget.org and change the `n` to a `f` to point to fuget.org. For example EPPlus 4.1.1's nuget.org URL is this: https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/4.1.1. Notice how nuget.org doesn't list anything under dependencies. Change the n to an f to get this url: https://www.fuget.org/packages/EPPlus/4.1.1. When you open that page, you see next to frameworks it says net35 and net40, so you can see that the package has binaries for .NET Framework 3.5 and .NET Framework 4.0.

Looking at the latest version of EPPlus, we see it has binaries for net35, net40 and netstandard2.0. While net35 and net40 are runtimes, netstandard2.0 is not, but if we look at the [docs page for netstandard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support), we can see that netstandard2.0 is implemented by .NET Core 2.0, .NET Framework 4.6.1, Mono 5.4, and others.